# twitter-bootstrap & twitter-bootstrap-js tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

There is a popular SO tag:  [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)

And for some strange reason we also have this tag:  [twitter-bootstrap-js](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-js) (13 questions)

Clearly the second tag needs to be merged into the first.

Presently, I am retagging the handful of questions.

Comment: This has been retagged by someone and the tag will disappear in the chron job since there are no question tagged with it anymore

Comment: @HugoDozois, my mistake... I misspelled the tag and since corrected my OP.  [tag:twitter-bootstrap-js] and I'm presently retagging the handful of questions left.

Comment: Well if you retagged them all, the tag will disappear in the next chron job that looks for unused tags!

Comment: We say *cron job*, I've no idea what a *chron job* is.